# how to change max recursion depth in Julia?

Tags: julia

I was curious how quick and accurate, algorithm from Rosseta code ( https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Ackermann_function ) for (4,2) parameters, could be. But got StackOverflowError.

```bash
julia> using Memoize
@memoize ack3(m, n) =
m == 0 ? n + 1 :
n == 0 ? ack3(m-1, 1) :
ack3(m-1, ack3(m, n-1))

# WARNING! Next line has to calculate and print number with 19729 digits!
julia> ack3(4,2) # -> StackOverflowError 
# has to be -> 2003529930406846464979072351560255750447825475569751419265016973710894059556311
# ...
# 4717124577965048175856395072895337539755822087777506072339445587895905719156733
```

**EDIT:**
Oscar Smith is right that trying ack3(4,2) is unrealistic. This is version translated from Rosseta's C++:

```bash
module Ackermann
  function ackermann(m::UInt, n::UInt) 
    function ack(m::UInt, n::BigInt)
      if m == 0
        return n + 1
      elseif m == 1
        return n + 2
      elseif m == 2      
        return 3 + 2 * n;
      elseif m == 3
        return 5 + 8 * (BigInt(2) ^ n - 1)
      else
        if n == 0
          return ack(m - 1, BigInt(1)) 
        else 
          return ack(m - 1, ack(m, n - 1))
        end
      end
    end

    return ack(m, BigInt(n))
  end
end

julia> import Ackermann;Ackermann.ackermann(UInt(1),UInt(1));@time(a4_2 = Ackermann.ackermann(UInt(4),UInt(2)));t = "$a4_2"; println("len = $(length(t)) first_digits=$(t[1:20]) last digits=$(t[end-20:end])")
  0.000041 seconds (57 allocations: 33.344 KiB)
len = 19729 first_digits=20035299304068464649 last digits=445587895905719156733
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Julia itself does not have an internal limit to the stack size, but your operating system does.  The exact limits here (and how to change them) will be system dependent.  On my Mac (and I assume other POSIX-y systems), I can check and change the stack size of programs that get called by my shell with `ulimit`:

```
$ ulimit -s
8192

$ julia -q
julia> f(x) = x > 0 ? f(x-1) : 0 # a simpler recursive function
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f(523918)
0

julia> f(523919)
ERROR: StackOverflowError:
Stacktrace:
 [1] f(::Int64) at ./REPL[1]:1 (repeats 80000 times)

$ ulimit -s 16384

$ julia -q
julia> f(x) = x > 0 ? f(x-1) : 0
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f(1048206)
0

julia> f(1048207)
ERROR: StackOverflowError:
Stacktrace:
 [1] f(::Int64) at ./REPL[1]:1 (repeats 80000 times)
```

I believe the exact number of recursive calls that will fit on your stack will depend upon both your system and the complexity of the function itself (that is, how much each recursive call needs to store on the stack).  This is the bare minimum.  I have no idea how big you'd need to make the stack limit in order to compute that Ackermann function.

Note that I doubled the stack size and it more than doubled the number of recursive calls — this is because of a constant overhead:

```
julia> log2(523918)
18.998981503278365

julia> 2^19 - 523918
370

julia> log2(1048206)
19.99949084151746

julia> 2^20 - 1048206
370
```

Answer (score 4):

Just fyi, even if you change the max recursion depth, you won't get the right answer as Julia uses 64 bit integers, so integer overflow with make stuff not work. To get the right answer, you will have to use big ints to have any hope. The next problem is that you probably don't want to memoize, as almost all of the computations are not repeated, and you will be computing the function more than 10^19729 different inputs, which you really do not want to store.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Although your assumption that changing maxdepth could not help seems to be true, there is at least one mistake in your answer. ack(4,1) without memoize had 2_862_984_010 calls and ack(4,1) with memoize only 163_846 calls. **And question about possibility to change max recursion depth remains! :)**